# Google Dialogflow: creating entity

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

While creating entity in dialog flow through nodejs... it throws an error saying:

> dialogflow.EntityTypesClient is not a constructor

The code is:

```
 const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
    const grpc = require('grpc');
    const prompt = require('prompt');

  // Instantiates clients
  const entityTypesClient = new dialogflow.EntityTypesClient();
  const intentsClient = new dialogflow.IntentsClient();

  // The path to the agent the created entity type belongs to.
  const agentPath = intentsClient.projectAgentPath('teamcenter-agent');

  const promises = [];

   const sizeRequest = {
    parent: agentPath,
    entityType: {
      displayName: 'size',
      kind: 'KIND_MAP',
      autoExpansionMode: 'AUTO_EXPANSION_MODE_UNSPECIFIED',
      entities: [
        {value: 'small', synonyms: ['small', 'petit']},
        {value: 'medium', synonyms: ['medium']},
        {value: 'large', synonyms: ['large', 'big']},
      ],
    },
  };
  promises.push(
    entityTypesClient
      .createEntityType(sizeRequest)
      .then(responses => {
        console.log('Created size entity type:');
        logEntityType(responses[0]);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('Failed to create size entity type:', err);
      })
  );
```

What is the issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: Please supply the relevant section of the code that produces the error so it becomes easier for others to suggest what might be wrong.

Comment: added the code...error occurs @line 4